# Trimming whitespace around text (like LTRIM, RTRIM and TRIM)

Tags: macros, spacing

When working in Excel with text strings, it is convenient to use the [LTRIM, RTRIM and TRIM functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080557211.aspx) which removes white space around text string. What would be an efficient way of duplicating this in LaTeX?

For example, say you programmatically produce variables

```
\def\firstname{FirstName}% First name
\def\lastname{LastName}% Last name
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}% Full name
\fullname% Display full name
```

yet should also accommodate for when `\firstname` *or* `\lastname` may be empty. Without testing whether they are empty, something like

```
\def\firstname{FirstName}% First name
\def\lastname{}% Last name (none)
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}% Full name
\trim{\fullname}% Display full name
```

would take care of this. My first thought was to define

```
\def\trim#1{\ignorespaces#1\unskip}
```

but this would most certainly not work in a general setting, since this does not take care of an empty group. Moreover, `\unskip` would only take care of the last skip, of which there may be more than one.

In particular, is it possible to define `\trim` such that it will take care of

- `\hspace`s and `\hskip`s?
- `\` 's?
- empty groups `{}` and perhaps non-printing tokens like `\relax`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Without \verb|\trim|:\par\medskip
\def\firstname{FirstName}\def\lastname{LastName}
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}\fbox{\fullname}

\def\firstname{FirstName}\def\lastname{}
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}\fbox{\fullname}

\def\firstname{}\def\lastname{LastName}
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}\fbox{\fullname}

\bigskip

With \verb|\trim|:\par\medskip
\def\trim#1{\ignorespaces#1\unskip}
\def\firstname{FirstName}\def\lastname{LastName}
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}\fbox{\trim{\fullname}}

\def\firstname{FirstName}\def\lastname{}
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}\fbox{\trim{\fullname}}

\def\firstname{}\def\lastname{LastName}
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}\fbox{\trim{\fullname}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Trimming all of the explicit spaces around input is certainly doable. There are a number of approaches about this problem: I would go with the one Bruno Le Floch wrote for `expl3` as `\tl_trim_spaces:n`. That can be used by doing

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \trimspaces \tl_trim_spaces:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Alternatively, the implementation can be included directly in the source and thus avoid any dependency:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\long\def\trim@spaces#1{%
  \@@trim@spaces{\q@mark#1}%
}
\def\@tempa#1{%
  \long\def\@@trim@spaces##1{%
    \@@trim@spaces@i##1\q@nil\q@mark#1{}\q@mark
      \@@trim@spaces@ii
      \@@trim@spaces@iii
      #1\q@nil
      \@@trim@spaces@iv
      \q@stop
  }%
  \long\def\@@trim@spaces@i##1\q@mark#1##2\q@mark##3{%
    ##3%
    \@@trim@spaces@i
    \q@mark
    ##2%
    \q@mark#1{##1}%
  }%
  \long\def\@@trim@spaces@ii\@@trim@spaces@i\q@mark\q@mark##1{%
    \@@trim@spaces@iii
    ##1%
  }%
  \long\def\@@trim@spaces@iii##1#1\q@nil##2{%
    ##2%
    ##1\q@nil
    \@@trim@spaces@iii
  }%
  \long\def\@@trim@spaces@iv##1\q@nil##2\q@stop{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\@gobble##1}%
  }%  
}
\@tempa{ }
\def\test{ foo }
\edef\test{\expandafter\trim@spaces\expandafter{\test}}
\show\test
```

This will remove all of the spaces from the ends of the input, even is you do something tricky like `\edef\test{ \space foo \space}` to start with (so there are multiple spaces at both ends). (If you are happy to limit yourself to this case, then [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) offers the `\TrimSpaces` post-processor for arguments using this method.)

The way the above works is that there are two loops: one for spaces at the start of the input (`\@@trim@spaces@i`),  a second for those as the end (`\@@trim@spaces@iii`). First, `\@@trim@spaces` sets things up such that the correct markers are in place. In the 'leading' step, `\@@trim@spaces@i` matches an argument consisting of `\q@mark` followed by a space (the space itself is discarded). If there are more spaces then `#1` and  `#3` will be empty and `#2` will be the remaining input, meaning that `\@@trim@spaces@i` will be called again with the remaining input. On the other hand, if there are no spaces left in the input then `#2` matches the empty input set up by `\@@trim@spaces`, `#1` is the user input with all leading spaces removed and `#3` is `\@@trim@spaces@ii`. The latter stops the loop and hands off to `\@@trim@spaces@iii` (a `\q@mark` is left on the front of the user input to prevent any loss of braces: see later). In this second loop, and spaces at the end of the input will appear just before `\q@nil`. This pattern is matched by the argument to `\@@trim@spaces@iii`. If there was a trailing space in the input then `#1` is the user input with the space removed (but still with a leading `\q@mark`) and `#2` is `\@@trim@spaces@iii`, leading to a loop. However, when the trailing spaces are exhausted, `#2` is `\@@trim@spaces@iv` and `#1` is the `\q@mark <user input>\q@nil\@@trim@spaces@iii`. The `\q@nil\@@trim@spaces@iii` is removed by the argument patter for `\@@trim@spaces@iv` before the leading `\q@amrk` is stripped off by `\@gobble` (with the `\unexpanded` preventing further expansion).

Note that the above uses e-TeX to allow it to prevent further expansion inside an `\edef` or similar. If the extensions are not available, change the last auxiliary to

```
  \long\def\@@trim@spaces@iv##1\q@nil##2\q@stop{%
    \@gobble##1%
  }%
```

with the proviso that this will mean that you do have to be cautious what is passed through.

A second thing to note is that there are some 'special' tokens in the above, for example `\q@nil`, that are used to match the macro argument patterns and so can't be in the input. That really should be okay with 'text', but you could use something even more obscure like `` \catcode`\Q=3 `` then `Q` (math shift catcode) if you wanted to.

Removing the other items requested would mean searching for all of them separately. That sounds quite tricky in the case of `\hspace`/`\hskip` as presumably the spacing could be given in any valid units, even before we worry about things like

```
\def\foo{10 pt }
\hskip\foo
```

As you may know, dealing with group tokens is tricky at the best of times, so finding an empty group could also be hard. (I guess you'd need to use a loop: grab each token in the input, see if it's empty and if it's not add it to the 'keep' pile.)

Moreover, I think that this sort of input is pretty unlikely in real input. Trimming explicit spaces make sense, but I am not convinced about the other items (unless there is some particular case here where there is a good chance of picking up the other items).

Comment: Note that Bruno's solution only needs e-TeX for `\unexpanded`, the idea being that you can use it inside an `\edef` without expanding the input any further once spaces are stripped.

Comment: I should give credit where it's due: my implementation is inspired to some extent by Heiko's package (I can't remember the name of the package, though).

Answer (score 5):

I definitely advise you to use Joseph's answer in practical use cases, even though it only removes explicit spaces, and not things like `\`  or `\hskip`.

Trimming such spaces from the right is straightforward (to some extent): `\unskip`, then repeat if the `\lastskip` is non-zero.  This can however be fooled if there is a skip of size `0pt`.

Trimming `\hspace` and friends from the left, also within macros forces us to manually perform all the macro expansions.  Even worse: since `\hspace` uses `\@ifnextchar`, we need to also perform assignments.  See code below.

Note that `\hspace*` uses TeX's primitives `\vrule` and `\penalty` for which I have implemented no support.  They will stop both `\trimleft` and `\trimright`.  I see how to fix that for `\trimleft` (at a dire cost), but not for `\trimright`, since TeX has no `\lastrule`.  LuaTeX could help.

```
\begingroup
  %
  % This plain TeX code uses the prefix "tsp", and defines
  % \trim, \trimleft, and \trimright.
  %
  \catcode`@=11
  \long\gdef\trim#1{\trimleft{\trimright{#1}}}
  %
  % Trimming spaces on the right is done by repeatedly calling \unskip
  % until \lastskip is zero.  We start with \hskip0pt\relax to stop
  % \trimright from trimming spaces _before_ #1 in case this only
  % contains spaces.
  %
  \long\gdef\trimright#1{\hskip0pt\relax #1\tsp@right}
  \gdef\tsp@right
    {\unskip\ifdim0pt=\lastskip\else\expandafter\tsp@right\fi}
  %
  % Trimming spaces on the left is done by repeatedly using \futurelet
  % to test the first token, and dispatching depending on what is found.
  % Expandable tokens are expanded; most assignments are performed;
  % spaces are ignored; groups are entered.  The loop ends when
  % encountering \tsp@left@end.
  %
  \long\gdef\trimleft#1{\tsp@left#1\tsp@left@end}
  \global\let\tsp@left@end\relax
  \gdef\tsp@left{\expandafter\tsp@left@look}
  \gdef\tsp@left@look{\futurelet\tsp@token\tsp@left@test}
  \gdef\tsp@left@test
    {%
      \typeout{\meaning\tsp@token}%
      \expandafter\ifx\noexpand\tsp@token\tsp@token
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \fi
      {% Expandable token => expand again.
        \let\tsp@next\tsp@left
      }%
      {%
        \ifcat\tsp@token\relax
          % Non-expandable primitive: build \tsp@<meaning>.
          % Note that primitives for which I haven't defined
          % \tsp@<meaning> just give \relax, which stops
          % trimming cleanly.
          \begingroup
            \escapechar-1%
            \global\expandafter\let\expandafter\tsp@next
              \csname tsp@\meaning\tsp@token\endcsname
          \endgroup
        \else
          % Character token.
          \ifcat\tsp@token\bgroup % Begin-group: do; continue trimming
            \bgroup\let\tsp@next\tsp@gobble@token
          \else
            \ifcat\tsp@token\egroup % End-group: do; continue trimming
              \egroup\let\tsp@next\tsp@gobble@token
            \else
              \ifcat\tsp@token\space % Space: remove; continue trimming
                \let\tsp@next\tsp@gobble@token
              \else % Anything else: stop trimming
                \let\tsp@next\relax
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi
      }%
      \tsp@next
    }%
  \gdef\tsp@gobble@token{\afterassignment\tsp@left\let\tsp@token= }
  %
  % Helpers for defining primitives.
  %
  \long\gdef\tsp@swap#1{#1\tsp@gobble@token}
  \gdef\tsp@assignment{\afterassignment\tsp@left}
  %
  % Various primitives
  %
  \global \let \tsp@unskip     \tsp@gobble@token
  \global \expandafter \let \csname tsp@ \endcsname \tsp@gobble@token
  \global \let \tsp@begingroup \tsp@swap
  \global \let \tsp@endgroup   \tsp@swap
  \global \let \tsp@def        \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@edef       \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@gdef       \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@xdef       \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@let        \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@futurelet  \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@global     \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@long       \tsp@assignment
  \global \let \tsp@protected  \tsp@assignment
  \gdef\tsp@hskip#1{\begingroup\afterassignment\tsp@hskip@\skip0= }
  \gdef\tsp@hskip@{\endgroup\tsp@left}
  %
  % We must end when seeing \tsp@left@end (normally \relax)
  %
  \long\gdef\tsp@relax#1%
    {%
      \begingroup
        \def\tsp@left@end{\tsp@left@end}%
        \expandafter
      \endgroup
      \ifx#1\tsp@left@end
      \else
        \expandafter\tsp@left
      \fi
    }
\endgroup

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Without \verb|\trim|:\par\medskip
\def\firstname{FirstName}\def\lastname{LastName}
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}\fbox{\fullname}

\def\firstname{FirstName}\def\lastname{}
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}\fbox{\fullname}

\def\firstname{}\def\lastname{LastName}
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}\fbox{\fullname}

\bigskip

With \verb|\trim|:\par\medskip
\def\firstname{FirstName}\def\lastname{LastName}
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}\fbox{\trim{\fullname}}

\def\firstname{FirstName}\def\lastname{}
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}\fbox{\trim{\fullname}}

\def\firstname{}\def\lastname{LastName}
\edef\fullname{\firstname\ \lastname}\fbox{\trim{\fullname}}

\end{document}
```