# Trim spaces in a macro with expl3

Tags: macros, expl3

I'm inserting graphics from data in a csv-file and due to lazy input I have to get rid of leading and trailing spaces. It works fine with the `trimspaces` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,graphicx}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\begin{document}

\def\testA{example-image-a }
%\includegraphics{\testA} %error

\def\testB{ example-image-a}
%\includegraphics{\testB} %error

\makeatletter
\trim@spaces@in\testA
\includegraphics{\testA}

\trim@spaces@in\testB
\includegraphics{\testB}


\end{document}
```

By curiosity I tried to get this with `expl3` and `\tl_trim_spaces:n` but didn't find a sensible way to store the content of the commands without the spaces in a command. Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69767/5764

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two ways. With the first method you use `\trimspaces` in front of the macro; with the second you can ‘normalize’ a macro to have leading and trailing spaces removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\trimspaces}{m}
 {
  \tl_trim_spaces:V #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_trim_spaces:n { V }

\NewDocumentCommand{\normalize}{m}
 {
  \tl_trim_spaces:N #1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\testA{example-image-a }
\def\testB{ example-image-a}

\includegraphics[width=4cm]{\trimspaces\testA}

\includegraphics[width=4cm]{\trimspaces\testB}

\normalize{\testA}\normalize{\testB}

\includegraphics[width=4cm]{\testA}

\includegraphics[width=4cm]{\testB}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I see. I hadn't understand that  \tl_trim_spaces:N does the same as \trim@spaces@in, I thought it would leave things in the input stream like  \tl_trim_spaces:n. And I hadn't thought about V type, I only tried x.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The description of `\tl_trim_spaces:N` could be clearer.

Comment: I can look to improve the docs for a release likely next week: @UlrikeFischer was there something specific that was missing?

Comment: @JosephWright Maybe “Resets *⟨tl var⟩* by removing any leading and trailing explicit space characters (explicit tokens with character code 32 and category code 10) from its content.”

Comment: @JosephWright: The main source of confusion was in my case the naming of the commands: Both `\tl_trim_spaces:n` and `\tl_trim_spaces:N` share the same command "body" `\tl_trim_spaces` and so I assumed that they are variants and do more or less the same only on different types of arguments and I transfered "leaves the result in the input stream" from the description of `\tl_trim_spaces:n` to the other command.