# How to remove space before or after argument then compare it with a string

Tags: macros, listofitems

I have this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\posa(#1) {%
    \ifx #1+ Plus \else \ifx #1- Minus\else Retry \fi \fi
}   
\begin{document}

    \posa(+)

\end{document}
```

Which compare argument of `\posa` command with `+` and `-`, I need to remove space before and after argument of `\posa` so that even if we wrote:

`\posa( +)` or `\posa(+ )` or `\posa( + )` we get `Plus` as result (same with -)

Comment: Related: [Trimming whitespace around text (like LTRIM, RTRIM and TRIM)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69767/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I use a `listofitems` package `\readlist*` to read the argument as a 1-item list, with leading/trailing spaces stripped.  Then I can do an `\if` (expanded) comparison on whether the list item is a `+` or `-`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def\posa(#1){%
    \readlist*\myarg{#1}
    \if+\myarg[1]Plus\else \if-\myarg[1]Minus\else Retry \fi\fi
}   
\begin{document}

    \posa(+)

    \posa( -)

    \posa(?)

    \posa( + )

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one needs the test to be done with the *non-expanded* argument of `\posa`, then this would suffice, since `\myarg[1]`, when twice expanded, yields the token(s) of the argument (leading/trailing spaces removed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def\posa(#1){%
    \readlist*\myarg{#1}
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tmp%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\myarg[1]}%
    \expandafter\ifx\expandafter+\tmp Plus\else%
      \expandafter\ifx\expandafter-\tmp Minus\else Retry \fi\fi%
}   
\begin{document}

    \posa(+)

    \posa( -)

    \posa(?)

    \posa( + )

\end{document}
```

In plain TeX, use `\input{listofitems}` instead of `\usepackage{listofitems}`.

Answer (score 2):

None of this is really latex, but since you are using def

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\posa#1#2#3{%
    \ifx +#2Plus\else \ifx-#2Minus\else Retry \fi\fi
}   
\begin{document}

    \posa(+)

    \posa( -)

    \posa(?)

    \posa( + )

\end{document}
```

Your original had a required space after the `)` but I removed that requirement here.

Note that it is safer to use `\ifx+#1` than `\ifx#1+` for example in your original if you use `\posa(zz)` the first test `\ifx #1+` would be true as it would test `z` and `z`.

Comment: How about argument `#1` and `#3` of `\posa`?

Comment: If I try with `\posa(zz)` a parenthesis appear  `Retry )`

Comment: @SalimBou `#1` is `(`  and `#3` is `)` (you could check that and raise an error if not.) `\ifx(#1\else \ERROR\fi` ...

Comment: @SalimBou why do you want the `()` in the arguments anyway? (which breaks all latex syntax guidelines) If you just had `\def\posa#1{\ifx+#1....` and `\posa{+}` or `\posa + ` it would be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I can explain why, but adding a second argument will suppress the spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\posa(#1#2){%
  \ifx+#1Plus\else\ifx-#1Minus\else Retry\fi\fi
}   
\begin{document}
    \posa(+)

    \posa( -)

    \posa(?)

    \posa( + )

    \posa(- )

    \posa(zz)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `xparse` we have easier syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\posa}{ r() }
 {
  \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } }
   {
    {+}{Plus}
    {-}{Minus}
   }
   {Retry}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

X\posa(+)X\posa( +)X\posa(+ )X\posa( + )X

X\posa(-)X\posa( -)X\posa(- )X\posa( - )X

X\posa(=)X\posa( =)X\posa(= )X\posa( = )X

\end{document}
```

[image]