# How \readlist* macro from listofitems package remove leading/trailing spaces

Tags: macros

This question follows [How to remove space before or after argument then compare it with a string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386340/how-to-remove-space-before-or-after-argument-then-compare-it-with-a-string/386354#386354)

The answer from @StevenB.Segletes use `\readlist*` macro which remove leading/trailing spaces from an item, can anyone help me understand how it is done. I took a look to `listofitems.sty` but I can't find where it is defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def\posa(#1){%
    \readlist*\myarg{#1}
    \if+\myarg[1]Plus\else \if-\myarg[1]Minus\else Retry \fi\fi
}   
\begin{document}

    \posa(+)

    \posa( -)

    \posa(?)

    \posa( + )

\end{document}
```

Comment: Look in `listofitems.tex`, which is pointed to by `listofitems.sty`.

Comment: The particular definition of interest is `\long\def\loi_removeextremespaces#1{\romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\loi_removelastspaces\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\loi_stop\loi_removefirstspaces{#1}}%
}`