# Check whether String represents valid number for PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, parsing

I am searching for a reliable way to determine whether a String can be fed into `\pgfmathprintnumber`. I used to use the `\IfDecimal` from the `xstring` package which works fine for things like `3.14` and similar inputs. However `\pgfmathprintnumber` can deal with scientific notation that will be sorted out by `\IfDecimal` because it thinks that it is not a number.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
    \def\testNum{3E+64}

    \IfDecimal{\testNum}{
        \pgfmathprintnumber[sci]{\testNum} is a number
    }{
        \pgfmathprintnumber[sci]{\testNum} is not a number
    }
\end{document}
```

As you'll see the number is properly recognized by `\pgfmathprintnumber` but not by `\IfDecimal`.

(I also tried the `\DTLisnumerical` command from the `datatool` package but it doesn't work either).

Does someone know a macro that will also detect scientific notations as numbers (preferably a validation by PGF itself - something that will try to parse the string with the mathematical engine but simply exits if the string can't be parsed as a number instead of killing LaTeX with an error)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so I did some extensive web-research and stumbled upon [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167369/checking-for-valid-floating-point-number) which had an interesting approach in the last answer. Furthermore I found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114127/using-nan-values-in-pgfplots).

As can be seen in the first linked question there is a key `/pgf/fpu/handlers/invalid number/.code` that defines the behaviour if a bad number format in `\pgfmathfloatparsenumber` is encountered. To quote the manual:

> This command key is invoked in case an invalid string is parsed inside
>   of \pgfmathfloatparsenumber. You can overwrite it to assign a
>   replacement \pgfmathresult (in float!). The initial setting is to
>   generate an error message.

From the second question I found out that there are flags indicating whether the parsed number was valid or not. So I combined the two of them to get

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}

\newcommand{\isPGFNumber}[3]{% \isPGFNumber{<Number>}{<True>}{<False>}
    \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/handlers/invalid number/.code={}}%
    \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{#1}%
    \global\pgfmathfloatgetflagstomacro\pgfmathresult\pgfFloatParseFlag%
    \endgroup
    \ifnum\pgfFloatParseFlag=3%
        #3%
    \else%
        #2%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}
    \isPGFNumber{3}{T}{F}\\
    \isPGFNumber{3.23}{T}{F}\\
    \isPGFNumber{.3}{T}{F}\\
    \isPGFNumber{3E+12}{T}{F}\\
    \isPGFNumber{3e-8}{T}{F}\\
    \isPGFNumber{3z}{T}{F}\\
    \isPGFNumber{Is there a problem?}{T}{F}\\\\

    %\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{z}
\end{document}
```

The `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` inside the macro definition is there in order to go back to the normal error-on-invalid-numbers-behaviour after having called the macro (Which can be tested by uncommenting the last statement in the document). As you can see it properly deals with the numbers even if provided in scientific format.

Comment: Remark: normally you want to use [expansion - Why the \expandafter\@firstoftwo idiom? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107753/why-the-expandafter-firstoftwo-idiom) for the conditional. Also as mentioned in the user's [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464646/250119) this doesn't work when the content inside expands to some erroneous thing...

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with regular expressions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for the test

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \raven_if_fpnumber:n { T,F,TF }
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { [eE] } { #1 }
   {% there is e or E
    \regex_match:nnTF
     {
      % optional sign,
      % optional integer part,
      % optional period,
      % optional fractional part,
      % one e or E
      % optional sign
      % mandatory integer
      \A
      [-+]?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+)
      [eE]{1}
      [-+]?[0-9]+
      \Z
     }
     { #1 } { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
   }
   {% no e nor E
    \regex_match:nnTF
     {
      \A
      [-+]?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+)
      \Z
     }
     { #1 } { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
   }
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \raven_if_fpnumber:n { x } { T,F,TF }

\NewDocumentCommand{\isfpnumberTF}{mmm}
 {
  \raven_if_fpnumber:xTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% for the test
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \texttt{\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}:
  \isfpnumberTF{#1}{\num{#1}}{``#1'' is not a number}%
}
\newcommand{\anumber}{3E+64}

\begin{document}

\test{\anumber}

\test{3}

\test{3.23}

\test{.3}

\test{3E+12}

\test{3e-8}

\test{3z}

\test{Is there a problem?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following builds upon tests I've implemented elsewhere. I did not remove everything unnecessary for this answer to work, so it might add more stuff than necessary. The test for a group in the argument is from [Check for group as argument (expandable)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422657/check-for-group-as-argument-expandable).

The test should be fully expandable.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\endMYifargument{\endMYifargument}
\newcommand\MYif@endMYifargument[1]% >>>
  {%
    \ifx\endMYifargument#1%
      \MYif@fiAa
    \else
      \MYif@fiBb
    \fi
  }% <<<
% MYif@fi macros >>>
\long\def\MYif@fiAa#1\fi#2#3{\fi#2}
\long\def\MYif@fiAb#1\fi#2#3{\fi#3}
\long\def\MYif@fiBa\fi#1#2{\fi#1}
\long\def\MYif@fiBb\fi#1#2{\fi#2}
\long\def\MYif@fiAy#1\fi#2{\fi#2}
\long\def\MYif@fiAn#1\fi#2{\fi}
\long\def\MYif@fiBy\fi#1{\fi#1}
\long\def\MYif@fiBn\fi#1{\fi}
\long\def\MYif@fifiAa#1\fi\fi#2#3{\fi#2}
\long\def\MYif@fifiAb#1\fi\fi#2#3{\fi#3}
\long\def\MYif@fifiBAa#1\fi\fi#2#3{\fi\fi#2}
\long\def\MYif@fifiBAb#1\fi\fi#2#3{\fi\fi#3}
\long\def\MYif@fifiBBa\fi\fi#1#2{\fi\fi#1}
\long\def\MYif@fifiBBb\fi\fi#1#2{\fi\fi#2}
% <<<
\newcommand*\MYif@groupify@TF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\edef\csname MYif#1GTF\endcsname##1%
      {%
        \unexpanded{\MYifGroupTF}{##1}%
          {\unexpanded\expandafter{\csname MYif#1GTF\endcsname}##1}%
          {\unexpanded\expandafter{\csname MYif#1TF\endcsname}{##1}}%
      }%
  }% <<<
\newcommand*\MYif@create@TandF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\edef\csname MYif#1T\endcsname##1%
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\csname MYif#1TF\endcsname}{##1}%
          {\noexpand\@firstofone}
          {\noexpand\@gobble}%
      }%
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\edef\csname MYif#1F\endcsname##1%
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\csname MYif#1TF\endcsname}{##1}%
          {\noexpand\@gobble}
          {\noexpand\@firstofone}%
      }%
  }% <<<
\newcommand*\MYif@create@TandF@twoargs[1]% >>>
  {%
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\edef\csname MYif#1T\endcsname##1##2%
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\csname MYif#1TF\endcsname}{##1}{##2}%
          {\noexpand\@firstofone}
          {\noexpand\@gobble}%
      }%
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\edef\csname MYif#1F\endcsname##1##2%
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\csname MYif#1TF\endcsname}{##1}{##2}%
          {\noexpand\@gobble}
          {\noexpand\@firstofone}%
      }%
  }% <<<
\newcommand*\MYif@create@N@TandF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\edef\csname MYif#1NTF\endcsname##1%
      {%
        \noexpand\expandafter
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname MYif#1TF\endcsname
        \noexpand\expandafter{##1}%
      }%
    \MYif@create@TandF{#1N}%
  }% <<<
\newcommand*\MYif@create@N@TandF@twoargs[1]% >>>
  {%
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\edef\csname MYif#1NNTF\endcsname##1##2%
      {%
        \noexpand\expandafter
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname MYif#1NNTF@a\endcsname
        \noexpand\expandafter{##2}{##1}%
      }%
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\edef\csname MYif#1NNTF@a\endcsname##1##2%
      {%
        \noexpand\expandafter
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname MYif#1TF\endcsname
        \noexpand\expandafter{##2}{##1}%
      }%
    \MYif@create@TandF@twoargs{#1NN}%
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\edef\csname MYif#1NnTF\endcsname##1##2%
      {%
        \noexpand\expandafter
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname MYif#1TF\endcsname
        \noexpand\expandafter{##1}{##2}%
      }%
    \MYif@create@TandF@twoargs{#1Nn}%
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\edef\csname MYif#1nNTF\endcsname##1##2%
      {%
        \noexpand\expandafter
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname MYif#1nNTF@a\endcsname
        \noexpand\expandafter{##2}{##1}%
      }%
    \expandafter\long\expandafter\edef\csname MYif#1nNTF@a\endcsname##1##2%
      {%
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname MYif#1TF\endcsname{##2}{##1}
      }%
    \MYif@create@TandF@twoargs{#1nN}%
  }% <<<
\newcommand*\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \MYif@create@TandF{#1}%
    \MYif@create@N@TandF{#1}%
  }% <<<
\newcommand*\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF@twoargs[1]% >>>
  {%
    \MYif@create@TandF@twoargs{#1}%
    \MYif@create@N@TandF@twoargs{#1}%
  }% <<<
\newcommand\MYif@notEmpty@noGroup@noSpace[2]% >>>
  {%
    \MYifEmptyTF{#1}
      {\@secondoftwo}
      {%
        \MYifContainsGroupTF{#1}
          {\@secondoftwo}
          {%
            \MYifContainsSpaceTF{#1}
              {\@secondoftwo}
              {#2}%
          }%
      }%
  }% <<<
% MYifEmpty >>>
\newcommand\MYifEmptyTF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \MYif@fiAa
    \else
      \MYif@fiBb
    \fi
  }% <<<
\newcommand\MYifEmptyT[1]{% >>>
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \MYif@fiAy
  \else
    \MYif@fiBn
  \fi}
% <<<
\newcommand\MYifEmptyF[1]{% >>>
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \MYif@fiAn
  \else
    \MYif@fiBy
  \fi}
% <<<
\newcommand\MYifEmptyNTF[1]% >>>
  {\expandafter\MYifEmptyTF\expandafter{#1}}% <<<
\newcommand\MYifEmptyNT[1]% >>>
  {\expandafter\MYifEmptyT\expandafter{#1}}% <<<
\newcommand\MYifEmptyNF[1]% >>>
  {\expandafter\MYifEmptyF\expandafter{#1}}% <<<
\MYif@groupify@TF{Empty}
\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF{EmptyG}
% <<<
% MYifContainsGroup >>>
\newcommand\MYifContainsGroupTF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \expandafter\MYifContainsGroup@a
      \MYifContainsGroup@eat#1{}%
    \MYifContainsGroup@endargument
  }% <<<
\long\def\MYifContainsGroup@eat#1#{}
\long\def\MYifContainsGroup@a#1\MYifContainsGroup@endargument% >>>
  {%
    \MYifEmptyTF{#1}
      {\@secondoftwo}
      {\@firstoftwo}%
  }% <<<
\MYif@groupify@TF{ContainsGroup}
\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF{ContainsGroup}
\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF{ContainsGroupG}
% <<<
% MYifContainsSpace >>>
\newcommand\MYifContainsSpaceTF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \expandafter\MYifContainsSpace@a
      \MYifContainsSpace@eat#1
    \MYifContainsSpace@endargument
  }% <<<
\long\def\MYifContainsSpace@a#1\MYifContainsSpace@endargument% >>>
  {%
    \MYifEmptyTF{#1}
      {\@secondoftwo}
      {\@firstoftwo}%
  }% <<<
\long\def\MYifContainsSpace@eat#1 {}
\MYif@groupify@TF{ContainsSpace}
\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF{ContainsSpace}
\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF{ContainsSpaceG}
% <<<
% MYifDigit >>>
\newcommand\MYifDigitTF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \MYifOneTokenNoGroupTF{#1}
      {\MYifDigit@a{#1}}
      {\@secondoftwo}%
  }% <<<
\newcommand\MYifDigit@a[1]% >>>
  {%
    \ifx0#1\MYif@fiAa
    \else\MYifDigit@b1#1%
    \else\MYifDigit@b2#1%
    \else\MYifDigit@b3#1%
    \else\MYifDigit@b4#1%
    \else\MYifDigit@b5#1%
    \else\MYifDigit@b6#1%
    \else\MYifDigit@b7#1%
    \else\MYifDigit@b8#1%
    \else\MYifDigit@b9#1%
    \else\MYif@fiBb
    \fi
  }% <<<
\newcommand\MYifDigit@b[2]% >>>
  {%
    \fi\ifx#1#2\MYif@fiAa
  }% <<<
\newcommand\MYifDigitGTF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \MYifGroupTF{#1}
      {\MYifDigitGTF#1}
      {%
        \MYifOneTokenTF{#1}
          {\MYifDigit@a{#1}}
          {\@secondoftwo}%
      }%
  }% <<<
\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF{Digit}
\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF{DigitG}
% <<<
% MYifNumber >>>
\newcommand\MYifNumberTF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \MYif@notEmpty@noGroup@noSpace{#1}{\MYifNumber@ifSign#1\endMYifargument}%
  }% <<<
\newcommand\MYifNumber@ifSign[1]% >>>
  {%
    \ifx+#1%
      \MYif@fifiAa
    \else
      \ifx-#1%
        \MYif@fifiBAa
      \else
        \MYif@fifiBBb
      \fi
    \fi
    {\MYifNumber@ifDigit@noend}
    {\MYifNumber@ifDigit#1}
  }% <<<
\newcommand\MYifNumber@ifDigit[1]% >>>
  {%
    \MYif@endMYifargument{#1}
      {\@firstoftwo}
      {%
        \MYifDigit@a{#1}
          {\MYifNumber@ifDigit}
          {\MYifNumber@false}%
      }%
  }% <<<
\newcommand\MYifNumber@ifDigit@noend[1]% >>>
  {%
    \MYif@endMYifargument{#1}
      {\@secondoftwo}
      {%
        \MYifDigit@a{#1}
          {\MYifNumber@ifDigit}
          {\MYifNumber@false}%
      }%
  }% <<<
\long\def\MYifNumber@false#1\endMYifargument% >>>
  {%
    \@secondoftwo
  }% <<<
\MYif@groupify@TF{Number}
\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF{Number}
\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF{NumberG}
% <<<
% MYifFloat >>>
\newcommand\MYifFloatTF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \MYif@notEmpty@noGroup@noSpace{#1}{\MYifFloat@a{#1}}
  }% <<<
%\newcommand\MYifFloat@a \newcommand\MYifFloat@ifDot >>>
\begingroup
\catcode`\?=4
\def\MYif@zz
  {%
    \endgroup
    \newcommand\MYifFloat@a[1]% >>>
      {%
        \MYifFloat@ifDot{##1}
          {\MYifFloat@withDot##1\MYifFloat@endargument}
          {\MYifNumber@ifSign##1\endMYifargument}%
      }% <<<
    \newcommand\MYifFloat@ifDot[1]% >>>
      {%
        \MYifFloat@ifDot@a##1.?\MYifFloat@endargument
      }% <<<
    \long\def\MYifFloat@ifDot@a##1.##2\MYifFloat@endargument% >>>
      {%
        \ifx?##2%
          \MYif@fiAb
        \else
          \MYif@fiBa
        \fi
      }% <<<
  }
\MYif@zz
% <<<
\long\def\MYifFloat@withDot#1.#2\MYifFloat@endargument% >>>
  {%
    \MYifEmptyTF{#1}
      {\MYifNumber@ifDigit@noend#2\endMYifargument}
      {%
        \MYifNumber@ifSign#1\endMYifargument
          {\MYifNumber@ifDigit#2\endMYifargument}
          {\@secondoftwo}%
      }%
  }% <<<
\MYif@groupify@TF{Float}
\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF{Float}
\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF{FloatG}
% <<<
% MYifContainsE >>>
\newcommand\MYifContainseTF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \MYifContainsE@e#1e\MYifContainsE@end
      {\@secondoftwo}
      {\@firstoftwo}%
  }% <<<
\long\def\MYifContainsE@e#1e#2\MYifContainsE@end% >>>
  {%
    \MYifEmptyTF{#2}%
  }% <<<
\newcommand\MYifContainsETF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \MYifContainsE@E#1E\MYifContainsE@end
      {\@secondoftwo}
      {\@firstoftwo}%
  }% <<<
\long\def\MYifContainsE@E#1E#2\MYifContainsE@end% >>>
  {%
    \MYifEmptyTF{#2}%
  }% <<<
% <<<
% MYifScientific >>>
\newcommand\MYifScientificTF[1]% >>>
  {%
    \MYifContainsETF{#1}
      {\MYifScientific@withE#1\endMYifScientific}
      {%
        \MYifContainseTF{#1}
          {\MYifScientific@withe#1\endMYifScientific}
          {\MYifFloatTF{#1}}%
      }%
  }% <<<
\long\def\MYifScientific@withE#1E#2\endMYifScientific% >>>
  {%
    \MYifFloatTF{#1}
      {\MYifNumberTF{#2}}
      {\@secondoftwo}%
  }% <<<
\long\def\MYifScientific@withe#1e#2\endMYifScientific% >>>
  {%
    \MYifFloatTF{#1}
      {\MYifNumberTF{#2}}
      {\@secondoftwo}%
  }% <<<
\MYif@groupify@TF{Scientific}
\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF{Scientific}
\MYif@create@TandF@N@TandF{ScientificG}
% <<<

\makeatother

\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
\def\testNum{3e+64}

\MYifScientificNTF{\testNum}
  {%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[sci]{\testNum} is a number
  }
  {%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[sci]{\testNum} is not a number
  }
\end{document}
```