# \newcommand with some empty inputs - unwanted space

Tags: macros

`\Opt` is a vector of 5 elements

[image]

but some of them can be left empty.

[image]

Based on [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/how-to-check-if-a-macro-value-is-empty-or-will-not-create-text-with-plain-tex-co) I learnt how to test if a parameter is empty or not.

But as you'll see in my MWE I struggle with spaces. I manually add an extra space in `\Opt{EMTN }{SPX }{jun }{ATM }{C}` but no doubt there is an automated answer to avoid double space when a parameter is empty and more harmoniously display the elements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\Opt}[5]{%
{\color{blue!80}% 
     \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\texttt{#1}\fi
} %I get a legit double space here if no %
{\color{orange!80!black} 
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else\texttt{#2}\fi 
    \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax\else\texttt{#3}\fi
    \if\relax\detokenize{#4}\relax\else\texttt{#4}\fi
    \if\relax\detokenize{#5}\relax\else\texttt{#5}\fi
}
}


\begin{document}

\Opt{EMTN }{SPX }{}{}{C}

\Opt{EMTN }{SPX }{jun }{ATM }{C}

\Opt{EMTN}{SPX}{}{}{C}

\Opt{FUND}{AAPL}{jun}{OTM}{C}

\Opt{FUND }{AAPL }{jun }{OTM }{C}

\Opt{}{SPX }{}{}{Put}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are adding a space at the start `{` one after `80}` one after `}` one after `black}` and another after `}` the `%` after `\fi` do nothing as white space after a command name is ignored, you need `%` on the _other_` lines to avoid adding space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Right, I updated MWE and the image of the result. If I'm not wrong, I now get some double space.

Comment: you are still adding a space after the `}` at the end and an (ignored) space after `{black}` plusa space here `} %` that percent does nothing if you leave a space before it. If you comment out all the spaces you are adding and remove the spaces in the arguments you should get no space in the result, then add spaces after the `\texttt{#2}` as you know in that branch they are non empty

Comment: Why not remove the space from the arguments and define thus: `\newcommand{\Opt}[5]{{\color{blue!80}\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\texttt{#1 }\fi
}{\color{orange!80!black}\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else\texttt{#2 }\fi\if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax\else\texttt{#3 }\fi\if\relax\detokenize{#4}\relax\else\texttt{#4 }\fi\if\relax\detokenize{#5}\relax\else\texttt{#5}\fi}}`. The calls would be `\Opt{EMTN}{SPX}{}{}{C}

\Opt{EMTN}{SPX}{jun}{ATM}{C}

\Opt{EMTN}{SPX}{}{}{C}

\Opt{FUND}{AAPL}{jun}{OTM}{C}

\Opt{FUND}{AAPL}{jun}{OTM}{C}

\Opt{}{SPX}{}{}{Put}`

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69767/5764

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the space in `\textt{#? }` and do `\unskip` after the last parameter:

```
\def\Opt#1#2#3#4#5{%
   {\color{blue!80}% 
       \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\texttt{#1 }\fi
   }%  I get a legit double space here if no %
   {\color{orange!80!black}% 
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else\texttt{#2 }\fi 
    \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax\else\texttt{#3 }\fi
    \if\relax\detokenize{#4}\relax\else\texttt{#4 }\fi
    \if\relax\detokenize{#5}\relax\else\texttt{#5 }\fi
   }%
   \unskip
}
```

test:

```
\Opt{EMTN}{SPX}{}{}{C}

\Opt{EMTN}{SPX}{jun}{ATM}{C}

\Opt{EMTN}{SPX}{}{}{C}

\Opt {EMTN} {SPX} {jun} {ATM} {C}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, merci.